# I need a Qt Runtime Installer or help with building one (WiX)

Tags: qt, installation, wix

I am trying to build an installer for a suite of products for a company I work for.  The software was built on Qt.  The suite of products will be distributed together and so I don't want to include/copy the dll's for Qt into each application folder.  I would either like to find an installer for Qt 4.7 runtime (hopefully as a merge module), or create my own.  Right now, I am creating my own WiX merge module, but when I try to compile the merge module I get the following error:

```
error LGHT0104 : Not a valid manifest file; detail: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 1, position 4.
```

I am new to the hell of dlls, so I am not sure what is wrong with the manifest file or if I am doing something else wrong.  Here is the manifest I created.  I am not sure if it is complete (1 manifest for 1 of 18 dlls):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
     version="4.7.2.0" 
     processorArchitecture="x86" 
     name="QtScript4.dll" 
     type="win32" />
    <file name="QtScript4.dll"></file>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the .manifest file in UTF-8 without a BOM. Since the error message indicates column 4, the first three bytes might be a bad BOM.

Comment: Thanks a million @bob-arnson, there was a hidden character at the beginning of the string, I would not have noticed that. Now that problem is fixed and I have a new one :).  Thanks for the input, really appreciate it.